# Exporting a template method creates multiple static variables in windows

Tags: visual-studio, templates, gcc, dll, c++17

I have a class in a library, if that class has a template method which has a static variable, using the method from within the library will access a different static variable than using the method from outside the library. This behavior happen in windows, in linux it works as expected.
I prepared an example with two scenarios, in both scenarios classes are defined in a library (LibA) and the test program is linked to it (temptest). Code is simplified in this explanation, full code is available in this github repository https://github.com/pyaggi/temptest. Example code uses cmake, so it will be easy to compile in any platform.

1- Scenario with a class template

```
//liba.h (library)
template<typename T>
class TestClass_template
{
public:
    TestClass_template()
    {

    }
    template<typename T1>
    static T1 incCounter()
    {
        static T1 counter=0;
        return counter++;
    }
private:
    T val;
};
class LIBA_PUBLIC TestClass_long:public TestClass_template<long>
{
public:
    TestClass_long();
    static short test_incCounter_short();
};



//liba.cpp (library)
TestClass_long::TestClass_long()
{

}
short TestClass_long::test_incCounter_short()
{
    return incCounter<short>();
}



//main.cpp (temptest, program)
std::cout<<"Output from class template example"<<std::endl;
for  (int c=0;c<2;c++)
{
    std::cout<<"TestClass<long>::incCounter_short "<<TestClass_template<long>::incCounter<short>()<<std::endl;
    TestClass_long::test_incCounter_short();
    std::cout<<"TestClass_long::incCounter_short "<<TestClass_long::incCounter<short>()<<std::endl;
    TestClass_long::test_incCounter_short();
}
```

Output in Linux

```
Output from templated class example
TestClass<long>::incCounter_short 0
TestClass_long::incCounter_short 2
TestClass<long>::incCounter_short 4
TestClass_long::incCounter_short 6
```

Ouput in Windows

```
Output from templated class example
TestClass<long>::incCounter_short 0
TestClass_long::incCounter_short 1
TestClass<long>::incCounter_short 2
TestClass_long::incCounter_short 3
```

In windows calling `TestClass_long::test_incCounter_short();` access a different static variable producing a sequencial output (0,1,2,3) in linux it access the same static hence producing an interleaved output (0,2,4,6).

2- Scenario with a regular class

```
//liba.h (library)
class LIBA_PUBLIC TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass()
    {

    }
    template<typename T1>
    static T1 incCounter()
    {
        static T1 counter=0;
        return counter++;
    }
    static short test_incCounter_short();
private:
    long val;
};



//liba.cpp (library)
short TestClass::test_incCounter_short()
{
    return incCounter<short>();
}



//main.cpp (temptest, program)
std::cout<<"Output from regular class example"<<std::endl;
for  (int c=0;c<2;c++)
{
    std::cout<<"TestClass::incCounter_short "<<TestClass::incCounter<short>()<<std::endl;
    TestClass::test_incCounter_short();
    std::cout<<"TestClass::incCounter_short "<<TestClass::incCounter<short>()<<std::endl;
    TestClass::test_incCounter_short();
}
```

Output in Linux

```
Output from templated class example
TestClass::incCounter_short 0
TestClass::incCounter_short 2
TestClass::incCounter_short 4
TestClass::incCounter_short 6
```

Ouput in Windows

```
Output from templated class example
TestClass::incCounter_short 0
TestClass::incCounter_short 1
TestClass::incCounter_short 2
TestClass::incCounter_short 3
```

Linux test was performed with g++ and clang.

Windows test was performed with msvc(cl.exe) and clang (msvc-cl.exe).

So I have two questions:

1- What is the expected behavior according to C++17 ?

2- Is it possible to make MSVC behave like linux ?

Comment: I could not reproduce your findings in scenario 1 and 2 with MSVC vc142. I get the same result like your Linux result. 0, 2, 4, 6. It does not matter, whether I put everything in one or two translation units. When I replace the definition of test_incCounter_short with its own implementation (without the template-redirection) I get 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (like expected). My guess: The compiler can easily detect, that your implementation of test_incCounter_short does directly invoke incCounter<short> and thus just replaces it.

Comment: My expected result is what I got in linux. I expect the compiler use the same implementation. But I don't know who is doing things out of the standard, or just maybe the standard is ambiguous. About your test on MSVC, did you compile the project from github ? the problem arises when you have a dynamic library, not just different compilation units, didn't test it with static linkage.

Comment: There is no standard for the behavior of exported classes. The topic is not covered by the C++ standard.

Comment: no, i did not use the github project

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, reading this excellent article [from Michele Caini](https://skypjack.github.io/2020-03-14-ecs-baf-part-8/), a great generic programmer; reading this [rejected bug report from Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/template-static-members-and-multiple-definitions-a/1202888). I can answer the two questions:

1- What is the expected behavior according to C++17 ?

None of the current revisions of the standard address the handling of libraries, crossing boundary codes are not standardized so it is up to the compiler designer.

2- Is it possible to make MSVC behave like linux ?
Well, the short answer is no. But sometimes there is a way to workaround this issue.

Xiang Fan at MSFT (check the bug report) proposed a solution using macro declarations to only define the templated static variable in one unit. That kind of solution just don't work in most scenarios because you defeat the whole purpouse of generic programing which is the idea that you don't know what kind of type will you be using and where.

I found a solution that works for me if the static variable you are creating doesn't depend on the template's type. You have to use a method or a global function that retrieves the static variable for you. This is not the case stated in the answer, but sometimes you can remodel the problem to go in this direction. I'll give you an example without classes for simplicity:

```
//example.h
unsigned long long &bigStatic() ;
template<typename T>
T incCounter()
{
    return static_cast<T>(bigStatic()++);
}

//example.cpp
unsigned long long &bigStatic() 
{
    static unsigned long long big=0;
    return big;
}
```